# При попытке запустить фрагмент из адаптера RecyclerVIew вылетает ошибка

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview, android-data-binding

текст ошибки:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sem.receivedata, PID: 21279
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sem.receivedata.databinding.FragmentNameListBindingImpl cannot be cast to com.sem.receivedata.databinding.FragmentDescriptionBinding
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.DescriptionFragment.onCreateView(DescriptionFragment.kt:28)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2995)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:523)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1758)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1670)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:317)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.adapters.NameListAdapter$NameListHolder.bind$lambda-0(NameListAdapter.kt:58)
```

`DescriptionFragment.kt:28` указывает на строку `binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_name_list, container, false)`

`NameListAdapter.kt:58` указывает на:

```
        activity.supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment)
            .commitNow()
```

`NameListHolder`:

```
class NameListHolder(val binding: NameListItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(paginationLocalModel: PaginationLocalModel, position: Int, context: NameListFragment){

        binding.name.text = paginationLocalModel.name
        itemView.setOnClickListener{

            val fragment = DescriptionFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt("position", position)
            fragment.setArguments(bundle)

            val activity=context.context as AppCompatActivity
            activity.supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment)
                .commitNow()

            Log.d("OnClick", "произошло нажатие по позиции $position")
        }

    }

}
```

`DescriptionFragment`:

```
class DescriptionFragment : Fragment() {

    private var binding : FragmentDescriptionBinding? = null
    private val descriptionViewModel : DescriptionViewModel by viewModel()

    val position: Int = getArguments()?.getInt("position", 0) ?: 0

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_name_list, container, false)

        binding?.name?.text = descriptionViewModel.loadDescription.value?.get(position)?.name
        binding?.date?.text = descriptionViewModel.loadDescription.value?.get(position)?.date
        binding?.description?.text = descriptionViewModel.loadDescription.value?.get(position)?.description

        return binding?.root
    }

}
```

Первый фрагмент (в котором находится RecyclerView) запускается внутри разметки `Activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/rd_fragment"
                android:name="com.sem.receivedata.presentation.NameListFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: `binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_name_list, container, false)` тут в `DescriptionFragment ` используется другой макет судя по названию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание на эти сторки:

```
private var binding : FragmentDescriptionBinding? = null
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_name_list, container, false)
```

Вам надо поменять

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_name_list, container, false)
```

На

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_description, container, false)
```